# Blueprint error multiple dashapp into flask

Tags: flask, plotly-dash, blueprint

I'd like to host multiple dashapp into a flak server. Each dashapp shall be accessible with a login and password.

Some users can access different dashapps.

I tried the dash_auth.BasicAuth. It works perfectly but only for one dashapp.

So I tried to authenticate with flask_httpauth. Here again, it works well for one dashboard, but not for 2 and more because of blueprints.

My flask_app.py:

```
import dash
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, Blueprint
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from flask_httpauth import HTTPDigestAuth

from apps.dashboard import Dashboard


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

#others routes

auth = HTTPDigestAuth()

users = {
    "john": "hello",
    "susan": "bye"
}
    
@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users.get(username)
    return None

url1 = '/dahsboard1'
dash_app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = app, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
dash_app1.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
dash_app1.layout = Dashboard(dash_app1, 'data1', 'Title1', url1).layout
@app.route(url1)
@app.route(url1 + '/')
@app.route('/dash1')
@auth.login_required
def render_dashboard1():
    return dash_app1.index()

url2 = '/dashboard2'
dash_app2 = dash.Dash(name='app2', server = app, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
dash_app2.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
dash_app2.layout = Dashboard(dash_app2, 'data2', 'Title2', url2).layout
@app.route(url2)
@app.route(url2 + '/')
@app.route('/dash2')
@auth.login_required
def render_dashboard2():
    return dash_app2.index()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The error:

```
ValueError: The name '_dash_assets' is already registered for a different blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide a unique name.
```

I undestand that a blueprint is created at each dashapp creation. After the first call :

```
print(app.blueprints)
```

returns

```
{'_dash_assets': <Blueprint '_dash_assets'>}
```

How can I add different blueprint names for each dashapp created ? Or more generally, how can I manage authentification for several dashapps running on one flask server ?

EDTIT:
I can solve this problem using this argument at dashboard creation

> url_base_pathname = '/fake-url/'

But it leads to another problem: I can't protect this route with

```
@app.route('/fake-url/')
@auth.login_required(role=['admin'])
def render_dashboard():
    return dash_app.app.index()
```

So the question is: how can I protect the route used in the dash creation with the argument url_base_pathname ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already solved this by now but will leave the solution here for the community. First you will need to set `url_base_pathname` for example:

```
dash_app2 = dash.Dash(
name='app2', 
server = app, 
url_base_pathname='/your_url_of_choice/'
external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```

This will resolve that error.